# Loading related mongoose data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Despite being a programmer for decades, I am really struggling with this synchronous, nested callback style of programming.

I have a schema like this (rails parlance)

- Property has many Photos
- Property has many Suites
- Suites has many Photos

When a user visits a property, I can get the Property and Suites just fine.

```
Property.findOne( {key: locals.filters.property}).exec(function(err, property) {
  locals.data.property = property;      
  Photo.find( {property: property._id }).exec(function(err,photos) {
    locals.data.photos = photos;        
    Suites.find( { property: property._id }).exec(function(err,suites) {
      locals.data.suites = suites;
      next(err);
    });
  });
});
```

This loads into req arrays fine right now.

My preferred method would be to have document methods resolve to the correct relationship documents, so in the template I could just do property.photos.each instead of separate unrelated arrays.   Yet I'm not sure if that's "the node way".   I need to keep the mongoose objects intact.

But how do I iterate over the suites and populate the photos?   Mongoose populate is not an option because there are not references on both sides.   Mongoose methods and virtuals are synchronous.

I know I am kind of forcing relational style relationships here, but I am working within the constraints of keystone.js so embedding is not an option.

The dataset is very small.   Plan B is to load everything up in the middleware and underscore slice and dice in the route.

Comment: Looking at that code block, I'd recommend reading up on the [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async). Beyond that, the fact that you aren't nesting documents somewhat defeats the point of Mongo. The idea isn't that it just fits in with "the node way", the idea is to make the data more accessible to prevent making multiple queries for reading data. Nesting documents (or minimized document schemas) allows you to do single database queries instead of the 3 that you're doing.

Comment: I think I am just going to embed the photos and lose out on some functionality.   It's a constraint of keystone.   This project doesn't have the resources for a full database crud layer, it's a quick and dirty type job.  Thanks.